# Partial trust XBAP & Windows Integrated Authenitcation - Fiddler hides problem

Tags: web-services, windows-authentication, xbap

I got a asp.net portal lanching a 3.5 sp1 partial trust XBAP. The portal is running under Integrated Windows Authentication, but I'm unable to make the XBAP run under integrated auth.

The XBAP downloads, and lanches fine, but once a call a WS on the same server (different web site) I get a 401 error. If I set the WS to use anonymous auth, everthing works fine.

Debugging using fiddler hides the problem (I guess fiddler is running as a proxy under my account, therefore the WS call works when fiddler is running)

Any idea on what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, forgot to set the UseDefaultCredintials=true; on the proxy